# tableviewcontroller with child detailViewController crashing with mysterious EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: ios, exc-bad-access

I have a parent table view controller with a readonly detail view controller property on it that lazily instantiates a detail view controller.  If I am on an iphone/ipod, I configure and push the detail view controller when an item in the table gets selected.  When the detail view is visible and I click back twice in the navigation controller, the detail controller then the parent controller get popped and the parent's dealloc gets called.  When the parent's dealloc reaches the line where I call [detailViewController release], I get a crash with EXC_BAD_ACCESS from the navigation controller.  That makes me think that my problem is with memory management of the detailViewController, but debugging with NSZombies shows no problems.  (Commenting out the [detailViewController release] line makes the crash go away but then I never have a release to balance out the detailViewController's alloc -- memorey leak)  Any ideas why I get this crash?

EDIT:
here's a stack trace for the crash:

```
Program received signal:  “EXC_BAD_ACCESS”.
(gdb) bt
#0  0x01046a63 in objc_msgSend ()
#1  0x0a9d72a0 in ?? ()
#2  0x0000cb4c in -[MyTableViewController dealloc] (self=0xa956840, _cmd=0x127a9d6) at /Users/nick/Documents/MyApp/Classes/MyTableViewController.m:290
#3  0x00390f1d in -[UINavigationController setDisappearingViewController:] ()
#4  0x0038e4f6 in -[UINavigationController _clearLastOperation] ()
#5  0x0038ee3f in -[UINavigationController navigationTransitionView:didEndTransition:fromView:toView:] ()
#6  0x0051be23 in -[UINavigationTransitionView _notifyDelegateTransitionDidStopWithContext:] ()
#7  0x0051cfd2 in -[UINavigationTransitionView _cleanupTransition] ()
#8  0x00308665 in -[UIViewAnimationState sendDelegateAnimationDidStop:finished:] ()
#9  0x003084f7 in -[UIViewAnimationState animationDidStop:finished:] ()
#10 0x0200c6cb in run_animation_callbacks ()
#11 0x0200c589 in CA::timer_callback ()
#12 0x01225fe3 in __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ ()
#13 0x01227594 in __CFRunLoopDoTimer ()
#14 0x01183cc9 in __CFRunLoopRun ()
#15 0x01183240 in CFRunLoopRunSpecific ()
#16 0x01183161 in CFRunLoopRunInMode ()
#17 0x01a5a268 in GSEventRunModal ()
#18 0x01a5a32d in GSEventRun ()
#19 0x002e642e in UIApplicationMain ()
#20 0x00001b28 in main (argc=1, argv=0xbffff070) at /Users/nick/Documents/MyApp/main.m:14
```

EDIT2:
dealloc method where the crash happens:

```
- (void)dealloc
{
    [context release]; // a managed object context -- when table entries are selected, they get cached in core data
    [tableDataArray release];
    [detailViewController release]; // <-- line 290, this is where it crashes
    [super dealloc];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've either:

A) Forgotten to retain the object stored to your `detailViewController` ivar

or

B) Released the object stored to your `detailViewController` ivar too many times

Thus when you attempt to release `detailViewController` in your `-dealloc` method, it's already been deallocated and points to invalid memory.  You should audit the places where you set the value of `detailViewController` in this class for one of these situations.  If you aren't seeing it, add the code where you manipulate that ivar to your question so we can examine it.

Comment: Turned out to be a variation of B--over-released a property I had on the detail view controller.  But you are right--EXC_BAD_ACCESS always seems to fall in one of those two categories.

Comment: Cool, glad I could help. When you get the chance, please mark my answer as accepted so other people the question has been correctly answered.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds very similar to an EXC_BAD_ACCESS crash I got recently.

If I remember correctly Xcode reported that it crashed on this line:

```
int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, nil);
```

and I think `NSZombie` reported that it was a `CALayer` that received the message.

**I'm guessing that your situation might be similar. Can you confirm this?**

Anyway, I was working on a proof of concept app, so we just let it leak and never actually fixed it. I know this doesn't solve your problem, but it might give you and other answerers more information. I myself wouldn't mind getting that leak fixed, so I hope this information helps towards solving it.

Comment: I don't get anything reported by NSZombie (even though its on), but I added a stack trace of the crash, if that helps.

Comment: @nick It's crashing in your dealloc. Posting MyTableViewController's dealloc implementation might help figuring it out.

Answer (score 0):

Well I ended up figuring out the error.  When I said in my original post that I *configure* and push the detail view controller, I had a memory management error (over-release) in one of the properties that I set on the detail view controller when configuring the detail view controller.  The error showed up in kind of an indirect way, but I caught it when I tried to recreate the bug in another, new, simpler VC.

Thanks to those who offered help.

Answer (score 0):

Try to retain detailViewController after you assign the value to it. If it works, it's a overreleased somewhere.